# How do I use flask render_template from a different directory

Tags: python, bash, flask, directory

I need some help. Let me explain my situation. Let's assume that the main flask project is in ~/project as an example. Now the directory structure looks like

- main.py
- templates

inside of templates there is index.html. This is a standard project.
Now if I was inside of ~ and I ran the command

```
python project/main.py
```

then I get an issue saying that Flask can't find index.html as a template. I assume the solution involves using the OS module. I'm not certain though.

The code for my main.py looks like this

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/')
def main():
  return render_template("index.html")

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

This works fine if i'm inside of the project directory. but not if i'm not in it

Can someone please help?

UPDATE: Using python3 instead of just python does not work.

Comment: add the code for the route which is failing i.e. the code which is supposed to render index.html but which fails

Comment: It works fine when run from the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Let me share it with you.

```py
template_dir = os.path.abspath('~/project/templates')
app = Flask('app',template_folder=template_dir)
```

this is where the templates folder is being stored. this location is static. No matter where you are running from.

Comment: In practice, this solution is not recommended. If project location was changed (someone pull your project other directories..), then your project will be broken and need to change code every location changes.

Comment: Thats very true, but as of now. As a matter of convencice. I believe this is the best option

Comment: To fix that issue, you would probably use some part of the OS module to get the location of the python file, and then get the templates folder from there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `FLASK_APP=project/main flask run` on home directory?

Comment: Not yet, but I did come up with a solution